# pow() function weird behavior when used in brackets and with long long integer

Tags: c, brackets, pow

I found something weird.

This function puts a digit in a number at the given spot and returns the modified number.
Now we want to do put_digit(123456789123456784, 0, 9);
That will put 9 at the end of the number, replacing the last number (4).

This is the code that WORKS:

```
long long int put_digit(long long int number, char place, char digit)
{
    long long int result = number;
    long long int power = number;

    power = pow(10, (place));
    result -= get_digit(number, place)*power;
    result += digit*pow(10, (place));

    return result;
}
```

The code returns 123456789123456789

This is the code that DOES NOT WORK:

```
long long int put_digit(long long int number, char place, char digit)
{
    long long int result = number;

    result -= get_digit(number, place)*pow(10, (place));
    result += digit*pow(10, (place));

    return result;
}
```

This code returns 123456789123456800 as the result.

The functions get_digit() returns the digit from the number in the given place.
This is it's code:

```
char get_digit(long long int number, char place)
{
    long long int target = number;
    char digit = 0;

    target /= pow(10, place);
    digit = target % 10;

    return digit;
}
```

• This does not happen with lower numbers.

• get_digit() always returns the correct value (4 in this case).

• get_digit() is a char because this is not a counter function, and thus it is better to focus on using less memory rather than using a faster variable like int.

• I've tried using brackets to avoid troublesome operator precedence, but to no avail.

• A weird behavior is also observed when doing put_digit(123456789123456000, 2, 7), which for some reason returns 123456789123456704. This is solved by replacing the pow function in the second result calculation with the variable "power".

I just don't understand why this is happening.

Am I getting some kind of an overflow? Is it my system's fault or my own? Am I using pow() in a bad way?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570, *6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions 1 [...] Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is double.*

Comment: Okay, so correct me if I am wrong, but the long long integer is being converted to double until the calculation is done, then suffers loss of precision due to the large number when converted back and assigned to the variable?

Comment: If you assign `long long x = pow(y,z);`, the result of `pow()`, which is of type `double`, is converted to `long long` by truncation. If you multiply `get_digit()*pow()`, the result of `get_digit()`, which is a `char`, is converted to `double`. Furthermore, compound-assigning `long long x -= (double)foo` converts `x` to double, does the subtraction and converts the result back to `long long`. Why you expect the result of this to be the same is beyond me.

Comment: Using floating point functions for exact integer calculations is broken by design.

Comment: the parentheses in `(place)` are useless and just reduces readability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration of `pow()` is: [`double pow( double base, double exponent );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow)

In the first case:

```
long long int power = number;

power = pow(10, (place));
```

the value returned by `pow()` is converted to `long long int` when it is assigned `power`. The rest of the computation is processed using integer numbers and the result is the one you expect.

On the second case:

```
result -= get_digit(number, place)*pow(10, (place));
```

the value returned by `get_digit(number, place)` is converted to `double` because it needs to be multiplied with a floating point number (returned by `pow()`). Also, the value of `result` is converted to `double` before subtracting the result of the multiplication. In the end, the computed value is converted from `double` to `long long int` to be stored in `result`.

But starting on some magnitude, the floating point numbers lose the precision of their least significant digit(s).

Try this simple piece of code to see for yourself:

```
long long int i = 123456789123456785;

for (; i <= 123456789123456795; i ++) {
  printf("long long int: %lld; double: %f\n", i, (double)i);
}
```

It outputs:

```
long long int: 123456789123456785; double: 123456789123456784.000000
long long int: 123456789123456786; double: 123456789123456784.000000
long long int: 123456789123456787; double: 123456789123456784.000000
long long int: 123456789123456788; double: 123456789123456784.000000
long long int: 123456789123456789; double: 123456789123456784.000000
long long int: 123456789123456790; double: 123456789123456784.000000
long long int: 123456789123456791; double: 123456789123456784.000000
long long int: 123456789123456792; double: 123456789123456800.000000
long long int: 123456789123456793; double: 123456789123456800.000000
long long int: 123456789123456794; double: 123456789123456800.000000
long long int: 123456789123456795; double: 123456789123456800.000000
```

This behaviour is not a bug but a limitation of the floating point numbers.

The solution for your code is to convert the value returned by `pow(10, place)` to `long long int` as soon as it returns:

```
result -= get_digit(number, place)*(long long int)pow(10, place);
```

Comment: Or even better, don't use `pow()` on integers. There's no guarantee that, for example, `pow(10.0. 10.0)` is exactly `1.0e10`. It's easy enough to write your own `pow`-like function that operates on integers.

Comment: I did see that pow() returns a double, but I never thought that my long long will be converted to double for the calculation, I thought that the result from pow() will be converted to an integer.
I guess writing my own pow function really might be the way to go.
Thanks.

One more thing:
If I declare
long int power; 
and do
power = (long int)pow(10, (place));
I get "-2147483648"
Is this because the power variable is overflowing?
Because I was doing that in the first place and I didnt think of using long long like in the example I gave.